# JavaScript using innerHTML and dynamic value passing to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var greentext='shopping';
var colors=new Array('green','blue','red','violet','brown');
for(i=0;i<colors.length;i++)
{
 //suppose consider colors[i] is green
}
```

When concatenating `colors[i]+'text'` and passing to some div using `innerHTML`, the string   `"greentext"`  is passed rather than the value of the concatenated string `"shopping"`. How to pass the value of dynamically created string as above?

Hope my question is clear.....please help me

Comment: How are you trying to assign the value? Please update your example.

Comment: I tried to assign value as document.getElementById('somedivname').innerHTML=colors[i]+'text';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it completely differently:

```
  var text = {
    green: 'shopping',
    blue: 'contemplating infinity',
    red: 'cooking beans',
    violet: 'writing poetry'
  };

  var colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red', 'violet' ];
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
    alert( text[ colors[i] ] );
  }
```

Structured data should preferably be represented with actual structures in whatever programming language you're using.  JavaScript is flexible enough that you *can* "construct" variable names, but it's not idiomatic.  Here, I've made a simple object with properties corresponding to your colors.